# pip install error under virtual env

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip, virtualenv

I am trying to install packages from inside the virtualenv
(Ubuntu 14.04LTS)

```
pip install scipy
```

I end up with the following error:

```
Collecting scipy
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 324, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 475, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 596, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/cachecontrol/adapter.py", line 47, in send
    resp = super(CacheControlAdapter, self).send(request, **kw)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 390, in send
    conn = self.get_connection(request.url, proxies)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 290, in get_connection
    proxy_manager = self.proxy_manager_for(proxy)
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/adapters.py", line 184, in proxy_manager_for
    **proxy_kwargs
  File "/home/rduser/venvs/python2713/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/_vendor/requests/packages/urllib3/contrib/socks.py", line 154, in __init__
    "Unable to determine SOCKS version from %s" % proxy_url
ValueError: Unable to determine SOCKS version from socks://10.0.0.28:8080/
```

How do I get past this.?
P.S: I am using the latest version of pip

Comment: Have you got installed `numpy`?

Comment: @Fomalhaut Yes, latest one. I installed that into virtualenv by downloading the wheel from pypi.

Comment: Maybe you could re-install `virtualenv` and after that install `scipy` using this instruction: https://www.scipy.org/install.html . Will it lead to this error again?

Comment: Scipy was just an example, it repeats the same error for any package that I try to get through pip

Comment: If you install packages not under a virtualenv, does everything go fine?

Comment: Yes, outside the virtualenv pip install works perfectly fine

Comment: Have you tried to re-install `virtualenv`?